# Creating a hook to a app?

Tags: c#, .net, c, windows, hook

Here is what I need.

I trying to write a application that will take over another application and intercept certain things that happens in it.
The idea is to monitor the application and take actions when some stuff happens.

After some research I found that Detours 2.1 from Ms Research, will help me, but I am having a hard time finding how to user it and integrate it in my domain of programming which is .NET.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this without having to dig c\c++ books.

Thanks all

Answer (score 3):

If your trying to hook another .NET application you could try [.NET Hook Library](http://dotnethook.sourceforge.net/).

If your talking about hooking system calls then there are actually lots of tools / libraries available.  Checkout "[Code Injection Tools](http://www.woodmann.com/collaborative/tools/index.php/Category:Code_Injection_Tools)" in the RCE tool library.

Answer (score 2):

There was an API and a layer added in Windows to assist in enabling desktop applications for users with disabilities.  I am not so sure about the current state of the API but I am quite sure equivalents exist in the .NET Framework.  Check out [this link](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMicrosoft_Active_Accessibility&ei=WZAwSpqeBYywNLLsxcsH&rct=j&q=microsoft+accessibility+api&usg=AFQjCNG-V0x7YxB3FmXcJet9jtdq7o8IGQ) and see if you can exploit the hooks built into this layer rather than going for lower level system calls.  The information suggests that Windows Automation API 3.0 is the current standard for intercepting events and manipulating another application.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Deviare](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/), the hook engine from our company where hooking is done trivially, injection and parameters parsing is done by the engine. This is for example a code in C# to intercept PrcStartDocPrinterW on spoolsv.exe.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Nektra.Deviare2;

namespace PrintLogger
{
    public partial class PrintLogger : Form
    {
        private NktSpyMgr _spyMgr;
        private NktProcess _process;

        public PrintLogger()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _spyMgr = new NktSpyMgr();
            _spyMgr.Initialize();
            _spyMgr.OnFunctionCalled += new DNktSpyMgrEvents_OnFunctionCalledEventHandler(OnFunctionCalled);

            GetProcess("spoolsv.exe");
            if (_process == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please start \"spoolsv.exe\" before!", "Error");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        private void PrintLogger_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NktHook hook = _spyMgr.CreateHook("spoolsv.exe!PrvStartDocPrinterW", (int)(eNktHookFlags.flgRestrictAutoHookToSameExecutable & eNktHookFlags.flgOnlyPreCall));
            hook.Hook(true);
            hook.Attach(_process, true);
        }

        private bool GetProcess(string proccessName)
        {
            NktProcessesEnum enumProcess = _spyMgr.Processes();
            NktProcess tempProcess = enumProcess.First();
            while (tempProcess != null)
            {
                if (tempProcess.Name.Equals(proccessName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && tempProcess.PlatformBits > 0 && tempProcess.PlatformBits <= IntPtr.Size * 8)
                {
                    _process = tempProcess;
                    return true;
                }
                tempProcess = enumProcess.Next();
            }

            _process = null;
            return false;
        }

        private void OnFunctionCalled(NktHook hook, NktProcess process, NktHookCallInfo hookCallInfo)
        {
            string strDocument = "Document: ";

            INktParamsEnum paramsEnum = hookCallInfo.Params();

            INktParam param = paramsEnum.First();

            param = paramsEnum.Next();

            param = paramsEnum.Next();
            if (param.PointerVal != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                INktParamsEnum paramsEnumStruct = param.Evaluate().Fields();
                INktParam paramStruct = paramsEnumStruct.First();

                strDocument += paramStruct.ReadString();
                strDocument += "\n";
            }

            Output(strDocument);
        }

        public delegate void OutputDelegate(string strOutput);

        private void Output(string strOutput)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                BeginInvoke(new OutputDelegate(Output), strOutput);
            else
                textOutput.AppendText(strOutput);
        }
    }
}
```

There are many alternatives to Deviare, Microsoft Detours is one of them. The main scope of Deviare is doing hooking extremely easy and being a COM object it can be used in .NET too via an automatic created interop. It is also trivial to use it on every scripting language like VBScript or PowerShell.